# Oracle join clause where varchar2(4 byte) causing issue

Tags: oracle, join

Title was tough to choose my wording.

I have 2 tables I want to join together via a lg_code. Both columns are VARCHAR2(4 byte).  I am running into an issue where table1 lg_code = 0003 and table2 lg_code = 3.  The three 0's are causing an issue with the join and not returning all the data needed. How would I go about writing the join clause to fix this issue?

Code:

```
select * from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.LG_CODE = t2.LG_CODE
```

Comment: If you want `'0003'` to match `'3'` then you will need to strip the zeroes off one side or add them on the other. Perhaps I am missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to convert the value of the column`lg_code` to number first then make the join:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON to_number(t1.LG_CODE) = to_number(t2.LG_CODE)
```

Comment: What if the column contains a string that doesn't convert to a number? (e.g. one day there is a row where `lg.code` = `'banana'`.) If all values in the column can be converted to number then you have to wonder why it was defined as a string in the first place.

Comment: The business always use numbers for this. I am honestly not too sure why they used a VARCHAR2 to begin with but I'm just creating a select statement to compare some info.

Comment: If the business 'always' puts numbers in this column then you need to assume that one day they will not.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use ltrim() on them:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON LTRIM(t1.LG_CODE, '0') = LTRIM(t2.LG_CODE, '0');
```

but in newer versions of oracle SQL*PLUS it trims automatically.

Comment: Not sure what new SQL\*Plus feature this is referring to?